# icontains and getlist django python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

We are trying to return a list of titles for the Django API, in which the title can have a few keywords.

So for instance, if we use the `__icontains` method to search for "money" and "world" (`api.com/?keyworld=money&keyword=world`) this will return all records that contain money, world or both.

The related SQL statement is:

```
select * from news
    where news_source = 1 or news_source = 2
        and news_title like '%money%' or news_title like '%world%'
```

We are trying to use this code to allow the user to have multiple keywords for the `__icontains` as well as multiple sources, so the end goal is:

```
api.com/?keyworld=money&keyword=world&source=1&source=2
```

**Our code:**

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    title = self.request.query_params.getlist('title')
    source = self.request.query_params.getlist('source')
    if title:
        queryset = queryset.filter(news_title__icontains=title, news_source__in=source)
    return queryset
```

The issue is that this is only returning the second keyword if a second keyword is used, and not other keywords prior to what is typed in `&keyword=`.

Comment: in get params you use `keyworld` but in filter `getlist('title')` is it correct? and please show example of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating 2 separate functions within the `get_querset()` function, which is called when a GET request is made.

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = News.objects.all()
        source_list = self.request.query_params.getlist('source')
        keyword_list = self.request.query_params.getlist('title')
        if source_list or keyword_list:
            def create_q_source(*args):
                list = [*args]
                source = Q()
                for value in list:
                    source.add(Q(news_source=value), Q.OR)
                return source
            def create_q_keyword(*args):
                list = [*args]
                keyword = Q()
                for value in list:
                    keyword.add(Q(news_title__icontains=value), Q.OR)
                return keyword
            queryset = queryset.filter(create_q_source(*source_list),create_q_keyword(*keyword_list))
        return queryset
```

**Edit:**
When you go to the api link and pass in the parameters, filtering will occur based on what is passed in:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notes/?keyword=trump&keyword=beyond&keyword=money&source=1
```

**SQL Equivalent:**

```
select * from news where news_source = 1 AND news_title like '%beyond%' OR news_title like '%money%'
```

Comment: Won't the fact that you initialize it with `Q(..)` result in the fact that *all* elements are accepted (since a `Q()` object matches *everything*, hence adding a condition with *or* logic, will not restrict the filter).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem With the above code, this will return me all of source 1 and source 2 content that contain keywords: trump and beyond in the title. At the queryset.filter() method, we are calling the functions that create the Q objects and returning them back to the filter method, so they in theory look exactly how you put them in your answer: qs.filter(
    Q(news_title__icontains=title1) | Q(news_title__icontains=title2),
    Q(news_source=source1) | Q(news_source=source2) | Q(news_source=source3)
)

Comment: I could also take out *args and list = [*args] on both functions and just say for value in source_list or keyword_list ---- i just realized that

Comment: yes, since `*args` are tuples an thus iterable as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can not perform an `__icontains` with a list, but you can for example design a function that, for a list constructs the logical or of these values. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def or_fold(list_of_qs):
    if list_of_qs:
        return reduce(or_, list_of_qs)
    else:
        return Q()

def unroll_lists_or(qs, **kwargs):
    return qs.filter([
        or_fold(Q(**{k: vi}) for vi in v)
        for k, v in kwargs.items()
    ])
```

You can then call the `unroll_lists_or` with a queryset, and each item should be an iterable (for example a list). It will then perform *or*-logic between the items of the list, and *and*-logic between different keys. In case an iterable is empty, it is ignored.

So we can then write the check as:

```
unroll_lists_or(queryset, news_title__icontains=title, news_source=source)
```

In case `title` contains two items (so `title == [title1, title2]`), and `source` contains three items (so `source = [source1, source2, source3]`), then this will result in:

```
qs.filter(
    Q(news_title__icontains=title1) | Q(news_title__icontains=title2),
    Q(news_source=source1) | Q(news_source=source2) | Q(news_source=source3)
)
```

You can however combine it with an `.filter(..)` for the `__in` check. For example:

```
queryset = News.objects.all()
if source:
    queryset = queryset.filter(news_source__in=source)
queryset = unroll_lists_or(queryset, news_title__icontains=title)
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my message. I have solved this a similar way, and im hoping you can take a look at my logic below just to see if that makes sense. Then i will still give you some credit here for pointing me in the right direction. I wanted to attempt to solve it myself after reading your post so that i can learn this framework.