# Django using icontains filter with multiple values from dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

Hi i'm trying to run a model search query through a **dictionary** data which i got like so:

```
{
   "city":5,
   "direction":"ne",
   ..other data that can be dynamic...
   "address__icontains" = ["word1", "word2", "word3"],
}
```

My search query:

```
 Models.objects.filter(**query_dict)
```

since the other data are **dynamic** that why i use filter with dictionary.And i'm using **__icontains** to search up field **address**(string value) that contains those 3 words in that string, so the problem right now is since **__icontains** doesn't accept **array** like so in the query set:

```
Models.objects.filter(other keys and values from dictionary, address__icontains= ["word1", "word2", "word3"])
```

How would i make this work with the dictionary filter search ?

my data in dict has 3 types string, int and list(1 for range search the other for icontains search) i would like to combine dictionary search with icontains AND search

I also tried changing the dictionary to

> "address__icontains" = "word1 word2 word3"

but it also doesn't work

Example data:

what im doing is find a Property that has an address field that has dynamic data like city, street, ward and district

For example:

> Đường ĐT 9(street), Xã Mỹ Hạnh Nam(ward), Đức Hòa(district), Long
>   An(city)

and it also has other data for example like direction="ne" and **specials** one that search between range so has key like "size__range": [0,1000] in the dict

for example if "address__icontains" = ["Long An", "Đức Hòa", "Xã Mỹ Hạnh Nam"] then it should return the above **Property** item with that address, direction="ne" and size has value between 0 and 1000

Thank for reading

Comment: It should be `address__icontains` not `"address__icontains"`

Comment: yes i mistyped sorry, fixed it

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list ?

Comment: so it will be like this ? Models.objects.filter(**query_dict, reduce(operator.and_, (Q(address__icontains=x) for x in ['word1', 'word2', 'word'])) since i also need the data from the dictionary be in the search after i remove the "address__icontains" key

Comment: oh it return error "positional argument follows keyword argument unpacking" after the **query_dict

Comment: keyword arguments must follow positional arguments.  Move any kwargs you have to the end of your function arguments, and you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: so what should i change it to ? since i need the data from **query_dict in the filter

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031710/10746224) of how this can be done

Comment: oh ok i didn't see the edit in time, it seems to work and i will try a few queries and test the results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [icontains and getlist django python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031397/icontains-and-getlist-django-python)

Comment: the query doesn't return anything even when the string of address has word1, word2 and word3 in it

Comment: Can you provide example data?  It should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce

instance = Model.objects.all()
def queryset_filter(instance, kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            instance.filter(reduce(or_, (Q(key=x) for x in value))
        else:
            instance.filter(key=value)
        return instance
```

You do a bit of extra iterating this way, but if your code requires more complex filtering (like using querysets from forms), then you will need to iterate in this manner anyways.

Comment: in the dict i also have 'road__range': [0, 1000] and i already use that for range search in filter so it's a list too

Comment: i had make an edit to my post with example data, if isinstance(value, list): can't be apply since some of the data is range so it's list type value