# How to write QuerySet syntax let field contains items in a list?

Tags: python, django

I know in Django I can use `__icontains` to query database use `LIKE`.

```
name = "joe"

Q(name__icontains=name)
```

but if I have a list:

```
name_list = ["joe", "klare"]
```

How can I write the QuerySet syntax let the name contains "joe" or "klare"?

Comment: objects.filter(name__in=name_list)

Comment: This might help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031397/icontains-and-getlist-django-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031397/icontains-and-getlist-django-python)

Answer (score 1):

By creating multiple conditions:

```
filters = Q()
for name in name_list:
    filters |= Q(name__icontains=name)

queryset.filter(filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic function for such operations, if you regularly make such queries with different properties

```
def generate_property_in_list_query(property_name, list_items):
    query = None
    for item in list_items:
        filter_query = Q(**{"{}__icontains".format(property_name): item})
        query = filter_query if not query else query | filter_query
    return query
```

Now you can create the query for **name** like

```
generate_property_in_list_query("name", ["joe", "klare"])
```

And the model filter opertaion will be

```
Model.objects.filter(generate_property_in_list_query("name", ["joe", "klare"]))
```

And if we want to search for some other properties, simply change the property name